# I have a linkedlist of 5 entries here, the process of adding information to the heap is not completed and I do not know where the error is

Tags: c

Stack Overflow ... I have a linkedlist of 5 entries here, the addition process of the information in the heap is not completed, and I do not know where the error is ... Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    char country_Name[20];
    int Population;
    int infe_people;
    int reco_people;
    int death_people;
    struct Node *next;
}*head;

void AddCountry(){
    struct Node *head = Null;
    struct Node *newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    printf("Country Name:\n");
    scanf("%s",&newNode->country_Name);

    printf("Number of Population:\n");
    scanf("%d",&newNode->Population);

    printf("Number of Infected:\n");
    scanf("%d",&newNode->infe_people);

    printf("Number of recovered:\n");
    scanf("%d",&newNode->reco_people);

    printf("Number of death:\n");
    scanf("%d",&newNode->death_people);
    newNode->next = null;

    if(head == null){
        head = newNode;
        newNode->next = null;
    }else{
        struct Node *temp = head;
        while(temp != null){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }

}
```

Comment: `head` is always `NULL` since you initialized it to it. Also I think it shadows the `head` which you declared when you made the struct.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

> the information in the heap is not completed

As said in comment in *AddCountry* you shadow the global var *head* with the local var, just remove the line

> ```
> struct Node *head = Null;
> ```

Using capitalized names for the global vars avoid that kind of confusion.

---

In

> ```
>     while(temp != null){
>         temp = temp->next;
>     }
>     temp->next = newNode;
> ```

you will dereference the null pointer, do

```
    while(temp->next != NULL){ /*<<< change here */
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = newNode;
```

---

I strongly encourage you to check the value return by *scanf* to know if you got or not a value rather than to suppose the input values are correct / exist

---

Also limit the length of the read string to not write out of the buffer, so replace

> ```
> scanf("%s",&newNode->country_Name);
> ```

by

```
scanf("%19s",newNode->country_Name);
```

because *country_Name* is an array sized 20, also note I removed the &

---

In :

> ```
> if(head == null){
>     head = newNode;
>     newNode->next = null;
>  }else{
> ```

it is useless to set again *newNode->next* because you already did few lines before

---

You use *null* and *Null*, probably you mean *NULL*

Answer (score 0):

First declaring a local variable head is wrong ,because this variable is only in `Addcountry` stack and it is invisible in other function.

```
struct Node {
    char country_Name[20];
    int Population;
    int infe_people;
    int reco_people;
    int death_people;
    struct Node* next;
}*head=NULL;//one head for all of your program ,don't declare other heads in functions
```

and since your function can insert the first node of the list ,you should change this function to return head node or pass `head node` by reference like this `void AddCountry(Node **head)`

in this `else` statement:

```
    else{
        struct Node *temp = head;
        while(temp != null){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
```

there are mistakes. After declaring `temp` first allocate memory for it ,then use it(and assign head to it).Also here you are dereferencing the Null pointer.

look

```
    else {
        struct Node* temp;
        temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp = *head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
```

And finally my advice is not using `int` for country population, since it probably need more space than that. change it with `unsigned long int` or `long int`.

here is the code:

```
struct Node {
    char country_Name[20];
    long int Population;
    int infe_people;
    int reco_people;
    int death_people;
    struct Node* next;
}*head=NULL;

void AddCountry(Node **head) {
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    printf("Country Name:\n");
    scanf(" %s", &newNode->country_Name);

    printf("Number of Population:\n");
    scanf(" %ld", &newNode->Population);

    printf("Number of Infected:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &newNode->infe_people);

    printf("Number of recovered:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &newNode->reco_people);

    printf("Number of death:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &newNode->death_people);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        *head = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;

    }
    else {
        struct Node* temp;
        temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp = *head;
        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}
int main()
{
    AddCountry(&head);//function call in main
}
```

also note those space I added to your `scanf` before arguments they are needed, otherwise you will probably have problem(because of `\n` at the end of your scanf).

PS: NULL not null.(might be problem)